# Where can I find documentation for Ubuntu Touch commands like webapp-container?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, documentation, manpage, info

Where can I find in ubuntu-touch something like man pages for commands such as `webapp-container`? I cannot find man or info pages onboard.Thanks.

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ man dpkg
bash: man: command not found
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ info info
bash: info: command not found
```

Comment: You can look at the files included with the package, see the output of `dpkg -L packagename`. Hopefully they have included some documentation or at least a README.

Comment: are you hoping to get documentation from within the ubuntu touch OS on a mobile device? or are you developing software on a desktop that they intend to run on an ubuntu touch instance eventually?

Comment: I am looking for manuals inside, or from, my Ubuntu-touch tablet. That is my only Ubuntu system. (I might build a laptop Ubuntu into an USB memory, if necessary)